# How do I solve the following differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $\frac{dy}{dx}+ \sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}=0$. How do I substitute $y$? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "substitute $y$"? This is a separable differential equation. Try to separate the variables and integrate.

Comment: I tried that but the answer comes in terms of inverse sine and the answer isn't in terms of sine

Comment: Oops, didnt see your comment. Anyways, what answer do you want?

Answer (score 7):

the DE is separable so:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = - \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\arcsin(y) = - \arcsin(x) + c$

$y = \sin[-\arcsin(x) + c]$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+ \sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}=0$$ or,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=- \sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}$$ or,
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=- \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ or,
$$\sin^{-1}y=-\sin^{-1}x+c$$ or,
$$\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}x=c$$

**EDIT**:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+ \sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}=0$$ or,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=- \sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}$$ or,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=- \sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2} \left(\frac{xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}{xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}\right)$$ or,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)=- \left(\frac{xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$ or,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{xy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=- \left(\frac{xy}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)$$ or,
$$-\sqrt{1-y^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{xy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=- \frac{xy}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \sqrt{1-x^2}$$ or,
$$d\left(-x\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)=d\left(y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$ or,
$$c-x\sqrt{1-y^2}=y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ or,
$$x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}=c$$

The method is quite laborious and boring. At present, I cannot remember the shortcut. I'll post it when it comes to my mind.

Comment: I got the same answer but it's not supposed to be in this form. Which is why I was trying to do it using substitution. But I don't get the answer that way

Comment: what answer do you want?

Comment: $x \sqrt(1-y^2) + y \sqrt (1-x^2) =c$

Comment: Okay you don't need substitution for that. I am doing it for you.

Comment: ani, are you in 12th?

Comment: @prakharlondhe Passed 12th this year. In college. Why do you ask this?

Comment: surely in iit? just because m preparing for jee and i liked your questions and answer on both physics and mathematics :). just needed to ask how can you think so well?

Comment: @Paradox101 Check if this helps you out.

Comment: From the expression $\sin^{-1}x + \sin^{-1}y = c$, simply take the sine of both sides to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @ZachMcDargh Please check mickep's answer. In general, you can't do so for there are restrictions on the values of x and y depending on which the formula changes. Using that formula means I am stringently imposing certain conditions on the values of x and y.

Answer (score 2):

First we note that $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and $-1\leq y\leq 1$ for the square roots to be real.

If you just want to be able to go from your solution
$$
c=\arcsin x+\arcsin y
$$
to the given solution you can apply sine to both sides and use the addition rule,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin c&=\sin(\arcsin x+\arcsin y)\\
&=\sin(\arcsin x)\cos(\arcsin y)+\sin(\arcsin y)\cos(\arcsin x)\\
&=x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here we have used that $\arcsin x$ and $\arcsin y$ belongs to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, so that, for example, $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

As a final comment, if you solve the differential equation in both ways, as is done by @Aniket, then you could conclude the addition rule for sine, if you did not have that one before. Similar addition rules for elliptic functions can be derived this way.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to solve it using variable separation.

Hint: take the under-root term to the right and then separate x and y containing terms. If you are still unable to solve it, consider the solution below (First TRY to do it yourself!)

Solution:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}$

$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=-\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

On Integrating,

$\sin^{-1} y = \cos^{-1}x\space $(or $-\sin^{-1}x) + C$

or $y=\sin(\cos^{-1}x + C)$
which is the required answer.

Comment: I tried it first using the separable method but the answer came out to be the same one you wrote. However, the answer that I should be getting is different

Comment: sorry, just read aniket's post.

Comment: u sure answer is right?